# Plot graphics frame Issue

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, rendering, version-13

**Bug introduced in 13.0 and persisting through 13.1. This bug is not present in macOS only in Windows.**

---

With Mathematica 13.1 I see the following issue with the right side frame changing based upon the number of elements plotted. Specifically, with 1000 elements the right-side frame line is shown but with 1024 (and other numbers of elements) the right-side frame line does not show. This was not occurring in prior versions.

I am looking for a consistent fix.

$Version: "13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

```
SetOptions[ListLinePlot, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans MT", FontSize -> 14}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold], ImageSize -> 500, 
  ImageMargins -> 20];

ListLinePlot[Range[1024]]
ListLinePlot[Range[1000]]
```

[image: Bad right-side frame]
[image: Good right-side frame]

Comment: The axes are correct and consistent for "13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

Comment: Also okay with `"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`

Comment: Strange, I have the same version 13.1.0  on Windows, but I do not see the error.

Comment: Some new details. When the plot is manually resized smaller the right-side frame often reappears. Resizing larger never corrects the issue. Also copying or "copy as bitmap" maintains the lost frame in the image.

Comment: I reproduce the problem with `"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`, but not with `"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)"`. Please report it to the support.

Comment: Still a problem in 13.2.0.

Comment: Same problem. Happens when I try to next two plots in a showed command, and outside the show use labelled to label x and y axes

Comment: A workaroud is to use ImagePadding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce the problem with `"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`, but not with `"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)"`. Please report it to the support.

The problem seems to be related to the global change in default value of the screen resolution compatibility setting for Windows in version 13.0.0, discussed in the following threads:

- [Mathematica 13: everything is magnified](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260927/280)
- [Why in Mathematica 13 do imported PDFs have lower image quality?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/263578/280)

You can reproduce the previous behavior by evaluating (**but read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261006/280) before you continue!**):

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode"] = True
```

Comment: I tied this work-around and it does correct the issue. However, it also requires restarting the kernel and the notebook since otherwise it causes large portions of the cells to blink and overwrite each other with different fonts or font sizes. I will report. Thanks.

Comment: No. If you do that, it will get the same problem on the left side. Try clicking on vector image produced by https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261535/geometrictest-doesnt-work-in-ellipse/274508?noredirect=1#comment685986_274508