# Did points in 2D graphics get moved since version 12?

Tags: graphics, upgrade

**Update:** Apparently this is a version 13.2.1 and Windows platform-specific problem.  I have submitted a tech-support request to WRI.

---

I am using version 13.2.1 on Windows. Notice that the lines do not pass through the centers of the points in the image below.  I don't recall that being the case before I upgraded from 12.0.  I've been using Mathematica since version 2.2, and don't recall this happening.  Did something change?

```
Graphics[{Thin, Line[.1 {{1, 0}, {0,0}, {0, 1}}]
  , Point[.1 {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}}]
  }, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Comment: Please notice that `O2` is undefined

Comment: Meh.  My bad.  Does it work now?

Comment: yup. very nicely, thanks. Unfortunately, I do not have `13.2.1` and in `13.2` it works fine. hopefully someone else will step in

Comment: @bmf What's your operating system? I have been this sort of slight misalignments on Mac for quite some while. I suspect it has something to do with "high DPI" displays.

Comment: @kirma I am on a macOS with `13.2` but I [**`don't see misalignments`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NDxm.png).

Comment: Looks right on v`13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)` and v`13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)`

Comment: @bmf Frankly I see a misalignment in that image, the point on the left doesn't lie exactly on middle of the line. More interestingly, it is misaligned differently on my display. This is not the most significant misalignment phenomenon I've seen, reported to WRI, and has been accepted as a problem by them, though.

Comment: @kirma thanks for sending the report and for verifying their answer. Not seeing the misalignment is probably my eyes getting a bit too old :/

Comment: @bmf This is really rather small difference on modern displays, and some effects I've seen are significantly larger. In this case one can experiment with the alternative of using `Disk`s: `Graphics[{Thin, Line[.1 {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}], Disk[#, ImageScaled[0.008]] & /@ (.1 {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}})}, ImageSize -> Small]` ... and `Rasterize`d images, and scaling them to see differences.

Comment: This is a bug on Windows system, no such problem on Linux or Mac OS. Another example is  about tangent line or tangent circles. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274508/72111

Comment: @cvgmt `Point`s are definitely not rendered with same location accuracy as `Disk`s  on Mac either. I believe rendering coordinates of `Point`s are rounded to some specific coordinate system which may not even correspond with the physical coordinate system on modern displays... but this is a small annoyance in comparison to the fact that coordinate axes and plotted zero values seem to also slightly disagree! (At least on my Mac: `Plot[Ramp[x], {x, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> Small] // Rasterize`- line on the negative side is clearly *below* the axis.)

Comment: @kirma typically, when I see something like that, I check my code, because what I thought was a correct mathematical expression just happens to evaluate to something close to the correct expression.

Answer (score 6):

This is a remnant from the days that all positions were integers for very fast drawing in Mathematica 2,3,4 or so. You can still see this behavior for certain graphical primitives in all versions (13.2 and even 13.3) in the output in Mathematica itself. Try scaling the Graphics object in the front-end (screenshot zoomed in a lot to make it more dramatic):

`Graphics[Point[Table[{i, 0.1 i}, {i, 100}]]]`

[image]

Note that in export and print this is all is fine. You can also see it does not happen with disks:

`Graphics[Disk[#, 0.5] & /@ Table[{i, 0.1 i}, {i, 100}]]`

[image]

*Source:* Rob Raguet-Schofield (former?) Mathematica developer, whom I contacted in 2010 on this very 'issue'.